# Variable Required error with TStream.Write()

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to compile a project but I guess this error "Variable Required"

```
function ReadInteger(SomeTStream:TStream):integer;
  begin
    SomeTStream.Read(Result, SizeOf(Result));
  end;

Top:=ReadInteger(SomeTStream);
Left:=ReadInteger(SomeTStream);
Height:=ReadInteger(SomeTStream);
Width:=ReadInteger(SomeTStream);
```

Then when it tries to write it stops in Top and Left.

```
SomeTStream.Write(Top,SizeOf(Top));
                    ^
SomeTStream.Write(Left,SizeOf(Top));}
                     ^
E2036 Variable required
```

I read about the problem in [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_need_var_xml.html)

But still I have no idea what should I do to fix it.

Comment: We need to see the declaration of Top, Left, height and Width. I guess that they are properties of an object. If so then you will need to use   local or member variables instead when calling Stream.Write

Comment: property cannot be passed by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly as the error says. The parameter must be a variable. But you are passing a property that is implemented using a getter function. Copy the property into a variable and pass that to the function.

```
var
  Value: Integer;
....
Value := Top;
Stream.Write(Value, SizeOf(Value));
```

Some helper methods would be most useful here to avoid drowning in boiler-plate. In fact you already added one for `ReadInteger` and you just need a matching one for `WriteInteger`.

```
procedure WriteInteger(Stream: TStream; Value: Integer);
begin
  Stream.Write(Value, SizeOf(Value));
end;
```

---

What's going on here is that the `Write` method of `TStream` is declared like so:

```
function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; virtual; abstract;
```

Because this function receives an untyped parameter, it cannot be passed by value. The address of the parameter is actually passed, and so the caller needs to supply something with an address. Your property does not fit the bill.

---

Incidentally, usually, `Write` and `Read` are the wrong methods to call on `TStream`. They do not perform any error checking. They leave that to you. The `Write` and `Read` are `abstract` methods that are used by specialized classes to provide the stream implementation. You are generally expected to call `WriteBuffer` and `ReadBuffer`.

---

Or perhaps a binary writer would help.

```
var
  bw: TBinaryWriter;
....
bw := TBinaryWriter.Create(Stream);
try
  bw.Write(Top);
  bw.Write(Left);
  // etc.
finally
  bw.Free;
end;
```

Comment: - *"A property does not fit the bill"* - I guess it is the getter that's the problem. You can pass 'tag' fine for instance.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Is that right. I always assumed that the compiler rejected all properties. Only one with functional getters is it?

Comment: Yeah, I even tested with a write only property, and it failed. I mean it refers to the backing field when it can.